# Why "final static int" can be used as a switch's case constant but not "final static <your enum>"

Tags: java, enums, constants, case, switch-statement

Why is this int switch valid:

```
public class Foo {
    private final static int ONE = 1;
    private final static int TWO = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int value = 1;
        switch (value) {
            case ONE: break;
            case TWO: break;
        }
    }

}
```

While this enum switch is not:

```
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

public class Foo {
    private final static RetentionPolicy RT = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
    private final static RetentionPolicy SRC = RetentionPolicy.SOURCE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RetentionPolicy value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
        switch (value) {
            case RT: break;
            case SRC: break;
        }
    }

}
```

I know that what goes in the case must be a constant, so why can I use a "final static int" as constant but not a "final static <your enum>"?

Comment: Why may I ask do you want to use the static var RT instead of just RUNTIME?

Comment: Because I have an enum Key {ZERO, ONE, TWO,...} that represent phone keys and depending on the context each key might mean one thing or another, so I declare constants with a more meaningful name, e.g. RETURN_TO_MAIN_MENU = Key.ZERO so that my switch cases are easer to understand by reading case RETURN_TO_MAIN_MENU: rather than case ZERO:

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because a case statement label must have either a compile time constant or an EnumConstantName. [JLS 14.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)

Compile time constants can only be strings and primitive types, as described by [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). Thus you can not use a static final <your enum>, as it is neither a compile time constant, nor the name of an enum.

Answer (score 8):

The case argument must be primitive; it cannot be an object.

However, you can use enums as follows:

```
RetentionPolicy value = ...
switch (value) {
    case RUNTIME:
    case SOURCE:
}
```

Because `value` is declared to be of type `RetentionPolicy` you can use the enum constants directly inside the switch.

Comment: `RetentionPolicy` **is** an enum.

Comment: @Michael: The OP used final static variables instead of direct references to the enum constants.

Comment: @Elite: Er...yes? What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it does not answer my question.  I know how to use a switch statement with enums as per your example.

Answer (score 2):

Or simply use a if-elseif case :

```
private final static int ONE = 1;
private final static int TWO = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 1;

    if(value.equals(ONE)){

    }
    else if(value.equals(ONE)){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler says

```
unqualified enumeration constant name required
```

So your value of `RT` would need to be `RUNTIME` instead of `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME` to make your code work. But of course that is not possible.  Why not use the `RetentionPolicy` enum directly? If you want to stick to your final static declaration, you need to assign the whole enum to your final static variable.

Comment: Did not understood your response.  If you want to know why I want to do that see the comment I added to my post.  Thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and worked around this problem by *switching on the Enums ordinal number* instead of switching on the enum itself. This is not very beautiful/intuitive but it works:

```
public class Foo {

    private final static int SRC = 0; // == RetentionPolicy.SOURCE.ordinal();
    private final static int RT = 2; // == RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME.ordinal();

    static{
        if (RT != RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME.ordinal() || SRC !=  RetentionPolicy.SOURCE.ordinal()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Incompatible RetentionPolicy.class file");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RetentionPolicy value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
        switch (value.ordinal()) {
            case RT: break;
            case SRC: break;
        }
    }

}
```

Note that it is of course not possible to declare the constant as e.g.

```
private final static int SRC = RetentionPolicy.SOURCE.ordinal();
```

for the same reason one is not able to declare the constant as an Enum in the first place...

Comment: That would work, but has non-deterministic knock on effects.  For example, if code is relying on ordinals, rather than Enum values, you'll run into trouble when you insert another enum value.   For clarity, consider that code could be splattered about which expects SOURCE.ordinal() to be 0.  You can't guarantee this, if someone changes the RetentionPolicy in the future.

Comment: Not entirely true: The code above is deterministic since the runtime check in the static initializer fails, if the ordinal numbers have changed for some reason. Of course this verification is very important and must not be omitted - thanks for pointing out this important detail!