# Difference between constant declarations

Tags: java

I have two java snippets using a constant in a switch case:

```
final Integer s1=5;
int x=5;
switch(x){
    case s1:  **<== causes complilation error..**
        System.out.println("hello");
}
```

The code below works fine as `s1` is treated as a constant, whereas the code above does not work.

```
final int s1=5;
int x=5;
switch(x){
    case s1: <=== ok s1 is constant
        System.out.println("hello");
}
```

What is the difference between the above two declarations?

Comment: Very close, but not quite a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401743/why-final-static-int-can-be-used-as-a-switchs-case-constant-but-not-final-st  (Answer applies here, too)

Comment: i don't understand what the question is.  OK,  you've seen that one of these works and the other doesn't.  You know what the difference is between them.  What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/329474/java/java/final-static-Integer-considered-constant

Comment: Another very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309692/difference-between-final-variables-and-compile-time-constant?rq=1

Comment: @DavidWallace I think it's a reasonable question. He's asking why a final Integer cannot be treated as a constant expression in a switch statement. I guess the answer is that the language designers could easily have made this work, but it would have complicated the definition of a constant expression, for no good reason.

Comment: @pbabcdefp OK.  So it's a "why did the designers do this" question.  I understand now.  Personally, I dislike such questions, because in most cases, they can only be answered by the designers of Java; and I'm not sure if any of them actually hang out on Stack Overflow.  But the fact that nobody here can possibly answer it doesn't make it an unreasonable question, I agree.  I find it amusing that two people have already tried, and no doubt more will follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java Language Specification [defines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> SwitchLabel:
>
> - case ConstantExpression :
> - case EnumConstantName :
> - default :

That is, a case label must either be the name of an enum constant, or a ConstantExpression. The spec also [says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-ConstantExpression):

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:

That is, an `Integer` is not a compile type constant expression, and therefore can not be used as a case label.

Answer (score 2):

`switch` statements only work on primitive types and `String`s and `enum`s. An `Integer` is neither a primitive type nor a `String` or `enum`, so it gives a compile error.

Comment: Hmm... but you can "switch" on an Integer, can't you (just not "case")?

Comment: I think it's more like what the error says: with Integer it's not considered a "constant expression". Nothing to do with "switch" directly.

Comment: It's an interesting question. Why auto-unboxing is not working here?

Comment: @pbabcdefp Whoops, forgot about those. Edited

Comment: yes, Switch takes on primitive and enumeration it does not work with Objects.